# std::map and function pointer as the value with different signature

Tags: c++, stl

I want to store function pointers with different signature in a `std::map` as a `value`. Is this possible in `C++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by using something like [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html) or [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html). Keep in mind, however, that you will have to remember somehow what the signature of the function stored (hidden) inside the `boost::any` object is, so you can retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need to use boost. You can simply use a functor( overload () operator) as a base class and inherit from it for every different function you need.

Comment: Sure, but it would be easy to change the functions from using a return type to reference parameters. Of course i agree to using boost, if you have no chance to change the functions returntype (3rd party/external functions)